# Tile map collision

Tags: c++, sfml

I've implemented a tilemap into my 2d game via vertex arrays by following a tutorial on the SFML website, but have noticed there's nothing on collision detection. What would be a good way of adding in collision detection between certain tiles and a player sprite?

Tile map class:

```
class TileMap : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
public:

    bool load(const std::string& tileset, sf::Vector2u tileSize, const int* tiles, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
    {
        // load the tileset texture
        if (!m_tileset.loadFromFile(tileset))
            return false;

        // resize the vertex array to fit the level size
        m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Quads);
        m_vertices.resize(width * height * 4);

        // populate the vertex array, with one quad per tile
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
            {
                // get the current tile number
                int tileNumber = tiles[i + j * width];

                // find its position in the tileset texture
                int tu = tileNumber % (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);
                int tv = tileNumber / (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);

                // get a pointer to the current tile's quad
                sf::Vertex* quad = &m_vertices[(i + j * width) * 4];

                // define its 4 corners
                quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);

            // define its 4 texture coordinates
                quad[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
            }

        return true;
    }

private:

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        // apply the transform
        states.transform *= getTransform();

        // apply the tileset texture
        states.texture = &m_tileset;

        // draw the vertex array
        target.draw(m_vertices, states);
    }

    sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
    sf::Texture m_tileset;
};
```

Comment: If a tile is an axis-oriented rectangle and so is the sprite, then a simple rectangle-rectangle intersection suffices.

Comment: But how would I know which tile/rectangle the player is intersecting with?

Comment: Check every tile and see what they're intersecting with. Depending on how you store your tiles you might be able to reduce that to only checking indices in a certain range around the character.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to have a field `obstacle` for the tiles that should be checked for collision. 
And then loop over the tiles checking if the obstacles collide with the player, then handle the collision if they do collide. Or better, having a list of only the obstacles so you don't have to loop over all the tiles each time.

```
for (auto const& tile : tiles) {
  if (tile.obstacle) {
    if (isColliding(tile, player)) 
      handleCollision();
  }
}
```